# Validate ajax post before save in Yii 2.0

Tags: php, json, ajax, validation, yii2

My problem is I want validate ajax post bib before save, to check table person `(bib, user_id)` is exist or not, if exist it can save this ajax post, but when it's not exist or wrong it's not save and give messsage wrong

**example data table person:**

```
bib | user id
==============
6   |  1
12  |  1
3   |  2
```

---

I send ajax post like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {pTableData: jsonEncode},
    success: function(msg){
        // alert(msg);
    },
});
```

**Example Output Ajax post:** `{[bib: 6, code: AS4], [bib: 12, code: AS4]}`

This is my controller to save ajax post:

```
if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
    $tableData = stripcslashes($_POST['pTableData']);
    $tableData = json_decode($tableData, true);      
    foreach ($tableData as $key) {
        $model->isNewRecord = true;
        $model->id = NULL;
        $model->bib = $key['bib'];
        $model->payment_code = $key['code'];
        $model->save();
    } 
        return $this->redirect(['index']);            
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model
        ]);
    }
}
```

- First, I want check when I login using user `id=1` it's check exist `bib=6 & 12` it's can save but went I login using user `id=2` it's can't save it because `bib=6 & 12` not exist in user `id=2`
- Second, When it's ajax post send example `bib=6 & 6` it's can't to save because same number

Comment: You need the 'exist validator' http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/validation-rules-for-model-attributes-in-yiiframework-2-0/#exist-validation

Comment: can you explain more? @Coz

Comment: You must check only 6 & 12 or there is more?

Comment: any more. it's just example data. bib it's a unique